# How to filter items with shuffling animation effect

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I want to achieve the spinning ajax page loading when we click on the filters as 
shown in the example http://demo.mattiaviviani.com/inbox/portfolio/themes....
I don't exactly know which jquery type is it? Please help me!!!

Comment: if i am not wrong you are asking about sortable portfolio using jquery.

Comment: @nbrooks OP asking about sortable portfolio not for loading image

Comment: @dipesh Then at the very best this is still 'not a real question', because it's impossible to figure out what OP actually wants, or give a reasonable answer. SO isn't a search engine. Any question that's just generating answers containing links probably shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully below links and example will help.

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/a-jquery-plugin-to-create-an-interactive-filterable-portfolio-like-ours

http://blog.gabrieleromanato.com/jquery-responsive-sortable-portfolio/

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Comment: Yes...http://razorjack.net/quicksand matches my requirement exactly.

Answer (score 1):

A simple glimpse at the source code shows a reference to PrettyPhoto for jQuery:
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Answer (score 1):

I think Fancybox will help you to achieve this. Try the below link.

[Jquery Fancy box](http://fancybox.net/)